# PostgreSQL - aggregate rows with similar values (+/- 1) in a dynamic way

Tags: sql, postgresql

here a portion of my psql data:

```
MODEL   YEAR    FUEL    POWER   RANGE   SAMPLES
model1  2016    diesel  102     2       1
model1  2016    diesel  103     2       2
model1  2016    diesel  115     2       25
model1  2016    diesel  133     2       10
model1  2016    diesel  134     2       7
model1  2016    diesel  135     2       54
```

I would like to aggregate every row that has:

- same model
- same year
- same fuel
- same range
- avg of every power value between (current_power-1, current_power+1)
- sum samples

and obtain something like this:

```
MODEL   YEAR    FUEL    POWER   RANGE   SAMPLES
model1  2016    diesel  102     2       3
model1  2016    diesel  115     2       25
model1  2016    diesel  134     2       71
```

About the first line (the result of the aggregation on the first 2):

```
model1  2016    diesel  102     2       3
```

the power 102 is the round(avg(*values involved*)) but it's not very important if the power will be 102 or 103

Considering that I have a great number of different model/year/power/range etc I cannot use any case-when-then condition with static value of power.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What if one of the rows had 104?

Comment: It is advisable to list what you have already tried and what didn't work in the question.

Comment: I inserted a new row (the one with power 115) to explain what I would like to happen in the case of power without close values

Comment: What is there also is a row with `power = 105`? Should 103 be grouped with 101 or with 105? Please describe the desired grouping in more detail.

Comment: The row with power 115 having no "close values" does not receive any aggregation

Comment: your resultant data makes no sense. 101 and 103  does NOT satisfy the condition "fall every power value between (current_power-1, current_power+1)" Still you have grouped them together

Comment: yes sorry I fixed the rows. I wrote the post with a simpler version of the data I actually have and I created a wrong situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can designate partitions in which the maximum difference of power between consecutive rows is greater than 2:

```
select 
    model, year, fuel, range, power, samples,
    (power- lag(power, 1, 0) over w > 2)::int as part
from my_table
window w as (partition by model, year, fuel, range order by power)

 model  | year |  fuel  | range | power | samples | part 
--------+------+--------+-------+-------+---------+------
 model1 | 2016 | diesel |     2 |   101 |       1 |    1
 model1 | 2016 | diesel |     2 |   103 |       2 |    0
 model1 | 2016 | diesel |     2 |   115 |      25 |    1
 model1 | 2016 | diesel |     2 |   133 |      10 |    1
 model1 | 2016 | diesel |     2 |   134 |       7 |    0
 model1 | 2016 | diesel |     2 |   135 |      54 |    0
(6 rows)
```

Next, use a cumulative sum to get these partitions over the whole dataset:

```
select
    model, year, fuel, range,
    round(avg(power), 2) as avg_power,
    sum(samples) as samples
from (
    select
        model, year, fuel, range, power, samples,
        sum(part) over w as part
    from (
        select 
            model, year, fuel, range, power, samples,
            (power- lag(power, 1, 0) over w > 2)::int as part
        from my_table
        window w as (partition by model, year, fuel, range order by power)
        ) s
    window w as (order by model, year, fuel, range, power)
    ) s
group by model, year, fuel, range, part
order by model, year, fuel, range, part;

 model  | year |  fuel  | range | avg_power | samples 
--------+------+--------+-------+-----------+---------
 model1 | 2016 | diesel |     2 |    102.00 |       3
 model1 | 2016 | diesel |     2 |    115.00 |      25
 model1 | 2016 | diesel |     2 |    134.00 |      71
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Op has changed the data again. it should be greater than 1

Comment: The original data was indeed slightly different. You can freely adjust the maximum difference between rows, the algorithm remains the same.

Comment: Many many thanks, it's really a fantastic solution! I would like to add that in my case I had to change the sql `(power- lag(power, 1, 0) over w > 2)::int as part` to `(power- lag(power::int, 1, 0) over w > 2)::int as part`. If I don't cast the power value inside lag function as int, PostgreSQL returns me this error: `error SQL [42883]: function lag bigint, integer, integer does not exist`. Anyway everything works properly. I ask you one last confirmation: to change the approximation value I simply have to change "2" in ` (power- lag(power, 1, 0) over w > 2)::int as part` right?

Comment: Ad 1. Formally `(power- lag(power, 1, 0::bigint) over w > 2)::int as part` should be better. Ad 2. Yes, that's right.

Comment: Yes `(power- lag(power, 1, 0::bigint) over w > 2)::int as part` works properly without any  `error SQL [42883]`. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT B.MODEL, B.YEAR, B.FUEL, B.RANGE, B.AVG_POWER POWER, B.SUM_SAMPLE SAMPLE
FROM yourTable A INNER JOIN
(SELECT MODEL, YEAR, FUEL, RANGE, AVG(POWER) AVG_POWER, SUM(SAMPLES) SUM_SAMPLE
FROM yourTable 
GROUP BY MODEL, YEAR, FUEL, RANGE) B
ON (A.MODEL=B.MODEL AND A.YEAR=B.YEAR AND A.FUEL=B.FUEL A.RANGE=B.RANGE)
WHERE B.AVG_POWER BETWEEN (A.POWER - 1) AND (A.POWER + 1)
GROUP BY B.MODEL, B.YEAR, B.FUEL, B.RANGE, B.AVG_POWER, B.SUM_SAMPLE;
```